# Spring MVC :How to do a GET request to another form on submit of a Form (POST)?

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

I have a form that extends `CancellableFormController`. On submit of this form, I want to do some processing with the data submitted and then generate another form using the processed data.

I have defined `successview` of first form as the `formView`of the `SecondForm`. When I submit my First Form it automatically goes to the Onsubmit of second form after onsubmit of first form, without generating the view of the second form.

Can somebody give me the basic idea of what all things I should define.

Comment: can You share some code?

Comment: What is you trying to achieve. Please elaborate